# How do I modify wpDataTables cell values using filters?

Tags: wordpress

In [wpDataTables](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpdatatables/), I would like to modify (i.e. conditionally format) each cell value in a specific column for a specific table programmatically using PHP. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

First, install the [Code Snippets plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/). Then create a new snippet set to "Run Snippet Everywhere" (required for JSON filtering) using the code below. It will filter both HTML and JSON. For more information, refer to [wpDataTables - Filters](https://wpdatatables.com/documentation/information-for-developers/filters/).

```php
function custom_wpdatatables_filter_initial_table_construct($tbl) {
    // Edit below.
    $table_name_to_modify = 'My Table Name';
    $table_column_to_modify = 'my_table_column';
    
    $cell_modification_function = function($value) {
        return 'Modified: ' . $value;   
    };

    // Check table name.
    if ($tbl->getName() !== $table_name_to_modify) {
        return $tbl;
    }

    $rows = $tbl->getDataRows();

    foreach ($rows as &$row) {
        if (array_key_exists($table_column_to_modify, $row)) {
            $row['intermentobituary'] = $cell_modification_function($row['intermentobituary']);
        }
    }

    $tbl->setDataRows($rows);

    return $tbl;
}

add_filter('wpdatatables_filter_initial_table_construct', 'custom_wpdatatables_filter_initial_table_construct', 10, 1);

function custom_wpdatatables_filter_server_side_data($json, $tableId, $get) {
    // Edit below.
    $table_name_to_modify = 'My Table Name';
    $table_column_to_modify = 'my_table_column';
    
    $cell_modification_function = function($value) {
        return 'Modified: ' . $value;   
    };

    // Check table name.
    $tableData = WDTConfigController::loadTableFromDB($tableId);
    if (empty($tableData->content)) {
        return $json;
    } else if ($tableData->title !== $table_name_to_modify) {
        return $json;
    }
    
    // Get columns.
    $columns = [];
    foreach ($tableData->columns as $column) {
        // wdt_ID will be first column.
        $columns[] = $column->orig_header;
    }

    // Modify column values.
    $json = json_decode($json, true);
    $rows = $json['data'];
    
    foreach ($rows as $row_key => $row_value) {
        foreach ($row_value as $row_attr_key => $row_attr_value) {
            if ( ! empty($columns[$row_attr_key]) && $columns[$row_attr_key] === $table_column_to_modify) {
                $rows[$row_key][$row_attr_key] = $cell_modification_function($row_attr_value);
            }
        }
    }
    
    $json['data'] = $rows;
    
    return json_encode($json);
}

add_filter('wpdatatables_filter_server_side_data', 'custom_wpdatatables_filter_server_side_data', 10, 3);
```